# Reset a sequence every year

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, query, sequence

Every time a new row is added to the table below, I want the sequence (Import Permit No) to be increased by 1....20160001, 20160002, etc and reset to 20170001, 20170002, etc in a new year.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblPermits](
[ImportPermitID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ImportPermitNo] [nchar](20) NULL,
[ImporterName] [int] NULL,
[Province] [varchar](50) NULL,
[LodgementDate] [datetime] NULL,
[PortofEntry] [int] NOT NULL,
[EstDateofArrival] [datetime] NULL,
[ConsignmentInvoicePONo] [varchar](50) NULL,
[OtherImportConditions] [varchar](400) NULL,
[Supplier] [int] NOT NULL,
[SupplierCountry] [varchar](50) NULL,
[CountryofOrigion] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_tblPermits] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ImportPermitID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Currently what I have is a trigger as shown below.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgPermitsInsertImportPermitNo]
ON [dbo].[tblPermits] FOR INSERT
AS 
UPDATE dbo.tblPermits
SET ImportPermitNo = 'IP' + CAST(YEAR(i.LodgementDate) AS CHAR(4)) + RIGHT('000000' + CAST(i.ImportPermitID AS VARCHAR(6)), 6) 
FROM dbo.tblPermits p
INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON p.ImportPermitID = i.ImportPermitID
```

But I couldn't get the sequence in the trigger above to reset to 0001 in a new year.

How do I modify the trigger to reset the sequence in a new year?

- Rows can be deleted from this table. Other rows would not get renumbered in that case.
- The number of new rows in a year is expected to be less than 5000, but in any case the number of prefix zeros could be expanded in the final design to accommodate a larger range.
- Lodgement Date is a normal datetime field to be entered by the user.
- All entries are made immediately when received from the client. Dates from previous years turning up late will not be an issue.
- Duplicate ImportPermitNo values are not allowed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012 or later, I would implement this using [sequence objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

For SQL Server 2008 R2, my replacement for that missing feature is [Sequence Tables](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/10/19/sequence-tables.aspx). In this case, there would be a key in the master sequence table for each year, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SequenceTable
(
    sequence_name   nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    next_value      integer NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK dbo.SequenceTable sequence_name]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (sequence_name),
);
GO
INSERT dbo.SequenceTable
    (sequence_name, next_value)
VALUES
    (N'PermitIDs for 2016', 1),
    (N'PermitIDs for 2017', 1),
    (N'PermitIDs for 2018', 1);
```

The standard allocation stored procedure to robustly allocate a key or range of keys from a sequence is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Allocate_TSQL

    @SequenceName       nvarchar(20),   -- The name of the sequence to allocate keys from
    @RangeSize          integer = 1,    -- The number of keys to allocate
    @FirstAllocated     integer OUTPUT  -- The first key allocated (output)

AS
BEGIN

    SET XACT_ABORT ON;  -- Most errors will abort the batch
    SET NOCOUNT ON;     -- Supress 'x row(s) affected' messages
    SET ROWCOUNT 0;     -- Reset rowcount

    -- Validate the range size requested
    IF (@RangeSize IS NULL OR @RangeSize < 1)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('@RangeSize must be a positive integer (supplied value = %i)', 16, 1, @RangeSize);
        RETURN  999;
    END;

    -- Initialize the output parameter
    SET @FirstAllocated = NULL;

    -- Update the row associated with @SequenceName, returning the 
    -- current value, and then incrementing it by @RangeSize
    UPDATE dbo.SequenceTable WITH (READCOMMITTEDLOCK)
    SET @FirstAllocated = next_value,
        next_value = next_value + @RangeSize
    WHERE sequence_name = @SequenceName;

    -- If @Allocated has a non-NULL value, we know we successfully updated a row
    RETURN CASE WHEN (@FirstAllocated IS NOT NULL) THEN 0 ELSE -999 END; 
END;
```

Then, given a simplified version of the table in the question:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ImportPermits
(
    ImportPermitID integer IDENTITY (1, 1)
        CONSTRAINT [PK dbo.ImportPermits ImportPermitID]
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    ImportPermitNo nchar(12) NULL,
    LodgementDate datetime NULL
);
```

We can assign sequence numbers per year using the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ImportPermitsImportPermitNo
ON dbo.ImportPermits
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 RETURN;   -- Return immediately if no rows affected
    SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON; -- Most errors abort the batch; no row count messages
    SET ROWCOUNT 0;             -- Ensure all rows are visible (local to trigger)

    DECLARE 
        @rc integer,
        @FirstAllocated integer,
        @RowCount integer,
        @Years integer,
        @SeqName nvarchar(20);

    -- Count rows and distinct lodgement years in the insert set
    SELECT 
        @RowCount = COUNT(*),
        @Years = COUNT(DISTINCT(YEAR(INS.LodgementDate))),
        @SeqName = N'PermitIDs for ' + 
            CONVERT(nchar(4), MIN(YEAR(INS.LodgementDate)))
    FROM Inserted AS INS;

    -- Check for multiple lodgement years (not implemented)
    IF @Years > 1
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Multiple LodgementDate years are not supported.', 16, 1);
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        RETURN;        
    END;

    -- Allocate the range of sequence numbers we will need
    EXECUTE @rc = dbo.Allocate_TSQL
        @SequenceName = @SeqName,
        @RangeSize = @RowCount,
        @FirstAllocated = @FirstAllocated OUTPUT;

    IF @rc <> 0
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Sequence allocation failed.', 16, 1);
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        RETURN;
    END;

    -- Assign ImportPermitNo values using the sequence numbers allocated
    WITH Sequenced AS
    (
        SELECT
            IP.ImportPermitNo,
            IP.LodgementDate,
            Seq = 
                @FirstAllocated - 1 + 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                    ORDER BY IP.LodgementDate ASC)
        FROM Inserted AS INS
        JOIN dbo.ImportPermits AS IP
            ON IP.ImportPermitID = INS.ImportPermitID
    )
    UPDATE Sequenced
    SET Sequenced.ImportPermitNo = 
        N'IP' + 
        CONVERT(nchar(4), YEAR(Sequenced.LodgementDate)) +
        RIGHT(N'000000' + CONVERT(nvarchar(11), Sequenced.Seq), 6);
END;
```

For brevity, the trigger is limited to inserting row(s) from a single year only, but it is not difficult to extend the logic.

**Demo:** [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=53b86165dd8e220881584f7f5a27b2fb)

Comment: ..thank you so much for your time and effort...your solution worked out perfectly....using it in all my projects...

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how heavily this table is used, could you try setting up a Sql Server Agent job that gets scheduled on the last day of the year at 23:59:50 (or around that time) that would begin a transaction, reseed the value of the identity to current year and a fixed '0001' - For year 2016, the identity would be 20160001 and for year 2017, the identity would be 20170001 - (Using a transaction effectively locks out other users to the table due to the open transaction) and wait for midnight (when you know the current year would be changed) and then commit the transaction?  Something like

```
begin transaction
declare @cmd nvarchar(500) = N'DBCC CHECKIDENT(''dbo.tblPermits'', RESEED,' + convert(varchar(4),year(sysdatetime())) + '0001)'
exec (@cmd)
waitfor time '00:00:00'
commit
```

Comment: In re-reading this question, yeah, you'd get a duplicate on identity 1 for 2016 and then identity 1 for 2017.  I've updated my answer to offer another suggestion which will only work if you don't actually care what value gets put in the identity column.  You'd basically reseed to a value that is the current year and then a hardcoded '0001'.  That should allow your trigger to work as you have it currently written.

Comment: @ScottHodgin, will try that out and get back...thanks

Comment: What if the SQL Server is down in that particular moment and no jobs are running @ScottHodgin-Retired? Perhaps the server is scheduled for maintenance, as the most quiet time of the year :P

Answer (score -2):

Old Post but with SQLExpress - store the Year value as a single field AppData in SQL Table. Before each record created of YYYY####### , Check Date Current Year against your stored year - if the Current Year is different - update your AppData Year Field with Current Year, reset your sequence counter - then you do your inserts ..

EDIT

If you have SQL Server Express Edition - you do not have agent jobs.
If you are trying to do this in SQL only - that means no power shell scripts to 'set a field' .
So that being said - you must verify that you are in a new year with in a transaction in order to determine if you should reset the sequence number. If a year value (current for the moment) is stored in a field of a control table. That field can be checked on transaction against current date getDate() and the sequence can be reset on [tblControl.Year != GetDate() Year]

Comment: I am not sure why the down votes .. If you have SQL Server Express Edition - you do not have agent jobs - so that is out, Transactions only occur on a transaction of some kind. So unless you verify that the current year is different than the year you have been using previously , in SQL Express with no SQL agents, and no power shell scripts etc.. there is not another way that I am aware of to do this.You have to know the previous year, and you have to know the current year (GetDate()).  Op does not state what Server Version to target - so I threw this one out there just in case.